# Make function call from highchart tooltip buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I need to pass point value from tooltip action button onClick event to parent component. I am trying to make function call on button click from highchart tooltip, so that i can pass point value to parent react component.
This is what i [tried](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-simple-chart-forked-h9h6ud?file=/chart.jsx). [image]

Comment: Have you try to use portals? Here is [example](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#how-to-add-react-component-to-a-charts-element) from official Highcharts wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the demo and I couldn't click the tooltip button, because the tooltip follows the cursor.

To do what you described you could create a function in a parent component with a passed `point` argument and pass the function as a prop to the children component, call that in onClick and pass the point.

Comment: you can hove on country and tooltip open, then you can move out of map and click button. passing of function not working. Looks like highchart only render it as html.

Comment: @user1583465 right, you could find this info in the [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter). Moreover, it has strong requirements for the HTML and CSS for `#formatter`. Why do you need to handle clicking in the tooltip, but not clicking on the map? According to the [doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.click) you could easily do that.